Always getting a make error with code 2 while trying to build nodejs-mobile for Android
If you have ever tried building the nodejs-mobile package for android, then you would be able to help me with this question. Whenever I try building the package, as per the docs I always get this kind of error at the end.
make: *** [node] Error 2

Now, I have tried all the architectures as stated in this link but still I keep the same error code at the end. If anybody has done this before please let me know how to fix this. Would be really helpful.
For the question as to why I want a custom build, is because the binaries that are already provided in this repository are built without full icu support.
Now, as Martin said, here is the stacktrace I am getting before finally getting this error
ar: ar: @/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/histogram/libhistogram.a.ar-file-listar: : No such file or directory
@/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.host/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_zlib.a.ar-file-list: No such file or directory
@/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/base64/libbase64.a.ar-file-list: No such file or directory
ar: @/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/simdutf/libsimdutf.a.ar-file-list: No such file or directory
ar: ar: @/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/llhttp/libllhttp.a.ar-file-listar: : No such file or directory
@/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/zlib/libzlib.a.ar-file-list: No such file or directory
ar: @/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/uvwasi/libuvwasi.a.ar-file-list@/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libplatform.a.ar-file-list: No such file or directory
ar: @/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/ada/libada.a.ar-file-listar: @/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.host/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libplatform.a.ar-file-list: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.host/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_zlib.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** Wa: iting for unfinished jobs....No such file or directory

make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/llhttp/libllhttp.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/zlib/libzlib.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libplatform.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/simdutf/libsimdutf.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/base64/libbase64.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/ada/libada.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/histogram/libhistogram.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.target/deps/uvwasi/libuvwasi.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/akhilrajnambiar/Nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-main/out/Release/obj.host/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libplatform.a] Error 1
1 warning generated.
rm 4cbf27825a36c641421e9f069b6ef108610efbc6.intermediate 2bf5713574d602ee90aa55e57347a60daccdd812.intermediate
make: *** [node] Error 2

Any help over here would be much appreciated. Also, the command I executed is the following
./tools/android_build.sh /path/to/android-ndk-r21b 24 arm64


I probably could answer that, while setting a bounty does not change the fact that make: *** [node] Error 2 could be just anything and the question is lacking a proper stack-trace, where one can see what may lead up to this final error-code. There's even an open issue filed for that: https://github.com/nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile/issues/20

This question is similar to: React Native on Android: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
